# Can android 4.1.2 with added APIs talk to bluetooth low energy?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I understand it wasn't until android 4.3 that BLE was fully enabled, however, are there libraries I can add such that I can get it working with 4.1.2?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to ask the manufacturer of your smartphone. Sometimes there are some libraries. Otherwise there is no chance to make it work.

Comment: Samsung supports an API for Android 4.2 - http://developer.samsung.com/ble , but there is no API for 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: No (on un-rooted devices)

The provided APIs are provided by the system and only the system can provide access to hardware elements.

Therefore an additional library can not provide you access to hardware the system does not already provide.

A different case are rooted devices. On such devices it may be possible. But on rooted devices the easiest way is to install a newer OS that has the functionality already included.